# Rate-limiting AJAX requests for updating content to avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch posts dynamically using AJAX and JQuery by checking if the user is close to the bottom. Serverside is in python on GAE.

Listening for scroll:

```
this.config.window.on('scroll',this.loadContent);
```

1.Checking for distance from bottom

2.Sending an ajax request with the number of current posts in order to retrieve the next 10

3.results.check = true means that the server has no further posts to send.

```
    loadContent: function(){
        // 1
        if($(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop() < 1000) {
            var posts = $('.troll').children('div').length;
            data = 'loadmore=True&offset=' + posts;   //2
            $.ajax({               
                url: '/',
                type: 'POST', 
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(results){
                    if (results.check === 'true'){  //3 
                        $(window).unbind('scroll');
                        return;
                    }
                    Post.insert10Values(results);
                }
            });
        };
    },

    insert10Values: function(results){
        var update = Handlebars.compile($('#troll10').html()),
            troll10update = update(results);

        $('div.troll').append( troll10update );
    }
```

The problem here is that when scrolling fast, two or more requests are sent to the server and i get duplicate entries. I want to rate-limit on client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag loading = false. Before you send a request, check the flag. If it's false, set the flag to true and proceed with request, otherwise ignore the event. When results arrive, show them and set the flag back to false.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem is scroll event will trigger many times a second

you can throttle any function calls doing something like this:

```
var scrollTimer=false;
var delay=500; /* 1/2 second*/
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
   if( scrollTimer){
       clearTimeout( scrollTimer);
   }

   scrollTimer=setTimeout(function(){           
       /* run your code here*/
   }, delay);

});
```

As for the ajax you could store a time for last ajax call and set a miniumum difference based on now vs stored time before making a new ajax call

```
var lastAJAX=Date.now(), AJAXMin=5000;/* 5 seconds*/

function checkAJAXCalls(){
    var now=Date.now(), diff=now-lastAJAX; 
    if( diff >= AJAXMin){
        lastAJAX=now;
         return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then run `if(checkAJAXCalls())` prior to making request. Concept could be modified to update `lastAJAX` in success callback of `$.ajax` also

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.ajax` has a method called `beforeSend`. It is executed right before your ajax call. You can use it to check if any other request is in progress and cancel the call if there is one. If you return false in `beforeSend` function, the ajax call will not be fired so you won't have any duplicate content.

```
$.ajax({               
    url: '/',
    type: 'POST', 
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        if (window.nextPageProcess) {
          return false;
        } else {
          window.nextPageProcess = 1;
        }
    },
    success: function(results){
        if (results.check === 'true'){  //3 
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            return;
        }
        Post.insert10Values(results);
          window.nextPageProcess = 1;
    }
});
```